# discord.py button on_interaction

Tags: discord, discord.py

```
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands
import json
from discord.ui import Button

with open('.\config.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)  


class button(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)
        
    @discord.ui.button(label="Button", style=discord.ButtonStyle.success, custom_id="ver")
    async def verify(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button:discord.ui.Button):    
        user = interaction.user
        role = interaction.guild.get_role(data['verify_role'])
        await user.add_roles(role)
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"success", ephemeral = True)

        
class verify(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot) -> None:
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_interaction(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        green = await bot.wait_for("button_click", check = lambda k: k.custom_id == "ver")
        await green.send(content="Button smashed!", ephemeral=False)

    @app_commands.command(name = "ver", description = "ver")
    async def verify(self, interaction: discord.Interaction) -> None:
        await interaction.response.send_message(view=button())



async def setup(bot: commands.Bot) -> None:
    await bot.add_cog(verify(bot))
```

I made a verify button, but when I reload the bot, I have to command it again. I want to use on_interaction to prevent him, but I don't have enough understanding of it. How do I get the button to work when the bot is reloaded?

Comment: Can you explain better what your code does?

Comment: I want the role to come in when I press the button.
The role assignment was successful, but if you turn off the bot, you have to enter the command again. Sorry for using a translator due to my poor English skills.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the view when the cog gets loaded for it to be a persistent view

```
class verify(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot) -> None:
        self.bot = bot
        bot.add_view(button())
```

Read more on `bot.add_view()`: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.add_view

Example of persistent views:
https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/views/persistent.py